# Getstream timeline,likes,comments and aggregated

Tags: python-3.x, getstream-io, facebook-timeline

Hi I Have to create a timeline feed activity like facebook. I give the likes and comments using reactions.but if i give the likes again to a same post by a same person the likes count get increased. how to resolve it.
 and how to use the aggregated feeds.. please give some example regarding this..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Multiple reactions from a user are allowed with the Stream API. We have a feature in the backlog to toggle this to allowed/not allowed, but I don't have an ETA for release. You can find aggregated examples here: https://getstream.io/blog/aggregated-feeds-demystified/